# How to make the image auto refreshed to get the new render view? Instead of browser cached

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome, opera

I have this following html code using jQuery getting refreshed but it does not show in the chrome browser the new image.

```
For example: 12.00AM - RED CAR driving
<div class="mycam_local">
          <img src="http://192.168.0.181:8008/liveimage/now.jpeg?1370446579000">
</div>

For example: 04.00AM - still RED CAR (basically its yellow one)
<div class="mycam_local">
          <img src="http://192.168.0.181:8008/liveimage/now.jpeg?1350446549000">
</div>
```

EDIT

```
$('.my_camera_brightness_up').live("click", function() {
  if (myb>1) {
    myb=1;
  } else {
    myb=myb+0.01;
  }    

  $.ajax({
    type    : "GET",//POST
    dataType: 'json',
    url     : '/a/c',
    data    : url + '&command=brightness;'+myb.toFixed(2),
    async   : true,
    beforeSend: function()
    {

    },
    complete: function()
    {            
    },
    success : function(msg)
    {
      $('.my_camera_buttonstate').html("Updated: " + myb.toFixed(2));
      var xy= "<img src=\"http://" + msg.extra.remoteip + ":7007/video/now.jpeg?"+ Date.parse(new Date().toString() ) + "\" />";
      //$('.mycam_local').find('img').attr('src',  'http://' + msg.extra.remoteip + ':7007/video/now.jpeg' +"?"+ Date.parse(new Date().toString()) );
      alert(xy);
      $('.mycam_lcoal').html(xy);
    }
  });    
});
```

Comment: you mean you get a blank image or still the older one? BTW, where is the code to refresh image?

Comment: So you want the images to auto fresh at a set time ? like 30 seconds, 1 minute, etc?

Comment: @roasted: i get the old one always.

Comment: YES i have 30 or 4 second events. Where this gets called. But its always showing old one

Comment: And are you sure your server returns a new image? Is it working as expected in other browsers? And how do you switch this image (CODE????)?

Comment: We need to see some code of how your image refresh works to know if that's the problem.

Comment: see EDIT above please. Yes the image is brand new live image but browser keep showing the image of 12:00AM.

Comment: It works the way i  showin in EDIT. By removing the html IMG tag and adding it as new. But it does not work if i simply do value change ex: `$('.mycam_remote').find('img').attr('src',  'http://' + msg.extra.remoteip + ':7007/video/now.jpeg' +"?"+ Date.parse(new Date().toString()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use this workaround:

```
$('.mycam_remote').find('img').attr('src','').attr('src', 'http://' + msg.extra.remoteip + ':7007/video/now.jpeg' +"?"+ Date.parse(new Date().toString()));
```

See if it works for you